# How to extract the first value in a grails object

Tags: grails

I have a grails object that I want to extract the first value in it. I'm new to grails and not understanding the language fully yet. 
I used a loop to extract them before but this time I just need the first value and nothing else.
I tried just using

```
<div id="blaa">${items}[0].value"</div>
```

That threw an error.

Below is usually how I would loop through the object.

```
             <g:each in="${items}" var="item" status="i">
                    <li><a href="#">${item.value}</a></li>
                </g:each>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making some assumptions here because you're not showing a lot of code and you also didn't tell us the error:

By default collections in Grails are Sets.  To get the first value in a set you could do something like:

```
${item.toArray()[0]}
```

Answer (score 2):

While @Gregg's answer is correct and will allow you to get the first element, there is an easier way and it's very close to what you tried:

```
<div id="blaa">${items[0].value}"</div>
```

The issue is that you need to have *all* of your "code" pieces within the `${...}` structure. Everything outside of that is just treated as a string.

As long as `items` is an ordered `Collection` (so, a `List`, a `Map`, or a `Range`, but not  a `Set`), you can access it like an array in Groovy (the language Grails is built in). @Gregg's answer explicitly converts `items` to an array first and then accesses it like an array.

Comment: Regarding your last point: although most collections can be indexed like arrays, this is not true for Sets.

Comment: @ataylor - Ahh, very true. I forgot that Sets don't have any concept of ordering built in, which is required for index-based access. I've updated my answer to reflect this. Thanks for correcting me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `${items.head().value}` to get the first value